# Determining the field of a struct given the field's offset

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, struct

Lets say I'm debugging a crash in optimized code. I look in the disassembly and I see something like the following:

```
lea eax,[edi+8Ch]
```

Now lets say I know what structure is being stored in edi, and in this case it's a somewhat large struct. Large enough that I can't tell at a glance what field that the 8Ch offset corresponds to.

What I have been doing is just opening up my watch window in Visual Studio and manually doing pointer arithmetic on a casted NULL pointer (what the offsetof macro would do) until I get the one that matches, but this is tedious. Is there a way I can more quickly determine which field is being accessed?

Comment: Is there a good reason you are reading disassembly to debug a C program?

Comment: Because the call stack doesn't accurately reflect what function I'm in due to a number of functions being inlined (and the crash itself is in an inlined function). I need to look at the disassembly to see where the crash actually occurred.

Comment: And this code can't be debugged in debug mode?

Comment: This is a crash dump I received, not something that happened locally. I suppose I could try to reproduce it, but sometimes being able to just quickly peek at the dump and get an idea of what's going on is quicker and more convenient than reproducing the conditions under which the crash occurred.

Comment: `cl.exe input.cpp /d1reportAllClassLayout > layouts.txt` will produce a dump of all classes/structs with their layouts. Unfortunately, it seems you need to compile as C++, not plain C (add `/TP` to force it to compile .c files as C++).

Comment: @DCoder That's great, but not all C code is C++ code, so it can be a lot of work to make it compile.

Answer (score 4):

In VisualStrudio you should be able to "watch" an expression like this:

```
(unsigned)&(((StructTypeName*)0)->StructFieldName)
```

You put in different field names until VS shows you the right offset value.

You can also load your app into `WinDbg` (make sure the symbols are loaded) and use the `dt` command. WinDbg will dump the layout/contents of the supplied type/variable name with the offsets of all the fields.

Comment: For the first suggestion, I already posted in my initial question that that is what I do currently, but on large structures it gets tedious to do a binary search through all the fields by hand. I'll have a look at WinDbg and see if `dt` does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to spend time with this debugging scheme, I would suggest writing a program that prints all the offsets of the structs fields, and list them in `offset; field` pairs.

I would go even further and write a script (in Python, for example) that takes the struct's text and generate a C code file that contains all the `offsetof` statements for all the struct's fields.

Comment: This seems like it would work, but it would be a pain - I'd have to have my script parse my whole program for cases where there are embedded structures or typedefs and be aware of how things are packed and aligned. It's be a pain to do it right and handle all the edge cases reliably.

Comment: [MSVC can give you this info, if you compile your code as C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735455/determining-the-field-of-a-struct-given-the-fields-offset#comment17209556_12735455). Yes, I'm aware that that might not be an option in some cases.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not an option in this case. The code is not C++ compatible. :-/